# Symfony Apache 2 : Unable to create the cache directory /var/cache

Tags: symfony, unix, apache2

I know this issue has been reported multiple times, but I tried every single solution and nothing seems to work.

I am running Symfony 3 on a Debian 9 Stretch, and theres a permission issue that I can't fix

`cat /var/log/apache2/project_error.log`

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Unable to create the cache directory (/var/www/mobileoutfitters.fr/public_html/var/cache/prod)\n in /var/www/mobileoutfitters.fr/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Kernel.php:676\nStack

In `/etc/apache2/envvars` :

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
```

My user is actually part of this group. I tried all the `chown -R 777` commands possible, and also as said in the Symfony documentation, these 2 commands :

```
HTTPDUSER=$(ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1)

sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:$(whoami):rwX var
```

I tried to delete the var folder, delete its content, clear the cache... But still this error.

Comment: check the owner of directories, maybe its root and your www-data can't create in there.

Comment: the directories are owned by my user, or by www-data depending on what I tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that my Symfony database was created but empty.

After running : `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force` it now works

Answer (score 0):

I had about the same issue, for me it worked after I disabled selinux on my local Centos virtualbox VM with `setenforce Permissive`.